# Total weekly hours worked excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an existing schedule format in excel where start and/end time is in a single cell.

eg: 09:00-17:30

[image: eg]

each employee has a row, each in the row is the shift time.

I need a formula to sum the hours worked in the month.

The only way I found so far is separate start/end time, then calculate for each day and sum

[image: eg]

any idea how this can be calculated with the existing format?

Answer (score 0):

SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RIGHT(B4:F4,5)-LEFT(B4:F4,5))
```

Then format the result: `[hh]:mm`

Note: This only works if your times do not go over midnight and always are on the same day.